# Two different types leading to the same instance in Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Say, that I have a class:

```
class A : IInt {}
```

I'm registering the class in Unity:

```
container.RegisterType<A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

I'd like to register IInt to the same instance of A as if anyone asked for A itself. So for instance:

```
A a = container.Resolve<A>(); // Should return instance of A
IInt i = container.Resolve<IInt>(); // Should return THE SAME instance of A
```

This should work the same way even if above statements were reversed - first asking for IInt, then for A.

How can I do it in Unity?

---

A possible, but rather ugly solution:

```
A a = container.Resolve<A>(); // To resolve A's dependencies
container.RegisterInstance(a);
container.RegisterInstance<IInt>(a);
```

Comment: But you shouldn't really be resolving `A` anywhere in your code. That's not the abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity will automatically deduplicate registrations on the background. This means that the following will yeild the expected results:

```
container.RegisterType<A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IInt, A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

This will prevent the type's lifestyle from being torn.

Resolving both `A` and `IInt` will yield the same instance.

You should *not* go with your proposed solution, because this is a dangerous practice. **You should never make any new registrations after you resolved from the container.** This is a bad practice, since it can leads to all kinds of unwanted side effects and bugs, and is blocked by most DI Container because of that.

For instance, [this article](https://simpleinjector.org/locked) described the problems that are involved with this Register-Resolve-Register anti-pattern with Simple Injector, but you'll find the problems to be identical with any other DI Container, such as Unity.